# azure app insights get a part of a string from url and display it in the name column

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using azure app insights and i want to parse a part of the string from url and show that part in a name column

```
requests
| where user_AuthenticatedId != ""
and url contains "reports" and user_AuthenticatedId == "xxx" 
| project timestamp, user_AuthenticatedId, client_CountryOrRegion, client_OS, url,name 
| order by timestamp asc nulls last
```

for example i am getting url as https://localhost:80/api/external-reports/blob/39/test 01b/false so i want to take the test 01b from this and show it in the name column.

i am not sure on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some functions that might be helpful.

First of all, you can get the different url parts using [parse_url()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseurlfunction) method. For example, given the url https://localhost:80/api/external-reports/blob/39/test 01b/false :

```
requests
| project parse_url(url)
```

output:

```
{"Scheme":"https","Host":"localhost","Port":"80","Path":"/api/external-reports/blob/39/test 01b/false","Username":"","Password":"","Query Parameters":{},"Fragment":""}
```

- You can split the result even further using the [split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/splitfunction) method:

```
requests
| project split(parse_url(url).Path, "/")
```

output:

```
["","api","external-reports","blob","39","test 01b","false"]
```

- To get the part you want you can use the index:

```
request
| project mycolumn = split(parse_url(test).Path, "/")[5]
```

output:

```
test 01b
```

- When an index is used that is greater than the number of parts an empty result is returned. You can replace it with a value of your own using the [coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction) function:

```
requests
| project mycolumn = coalesce(split(parse_url(test).Path, "/")[5], "unknown")
```

it shows unknown when the index is out of range or the part is empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i was looking for.